# Opencart sort by bestselling product

Tags: sorting, opencart, product

I'm trying to add **sort by best selling product** in category page.
To do this I added the code below in `catalog/controller/product/category.php` controller:

```
$this->data['sorts'][] = array(
    'text'  => 'Bestsellers',
    'value' => 'bestsellers',
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=bestsellers&order=DESC' . $url)
);
```

After adding this I can see *Bestsellers* option in sorting list. Now I'm trying to do a database query to complete this sorting. I tried to clone the existing sorting like *Sort by Name (A-z)* but because I'm new to opencart I am not able to do this.

Could You please share your ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I will just guide You, the query part is up on to You...

Edit also the `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` - method `getProducts($data)`. Check for this part:

```php
$sort_data = array(
    'pd.name',
    'p.model',
    'p.quantity',
    'p.price',
    'rating',
    'p.sort_order',
    'p.date_added'
);
```

and add Your new sorting, e.g. `bestsellers`, so You'll end up with this array:

```php
$sort_data = array(
    'pd.name',
    'p.model',
    'p.quantity',
    'p.price',
    'rating',
    'p.sort_order',
    'p.date_added',
    'bestsellers',
);
```

Now You would have to edit the next part starting with `if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {` so You should end up with:

```php
if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
    if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
    } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'bestsellers') { // <-- YOUR NEW SORTING
        $sql .= " ORDER BY <ADD YOUR SORTING QUERY HERE>";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    }
} else {
    $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
}
```

After adding the right query instead of `<ADD YOUR SORTING QUERY HERE>` You should be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply shadyyx... I'm getting error after adding below query. SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM oc_order_product You can check the error in https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2cb5goyjw8qkhj/error.txt

Comment: @Vin_fugen You are missing `ORDER BY` keyword and You didn't left a `space` before Your query... Show me the code You have added instead of the line `$sql .= " ORDER BY <ADD YOUR SORTING QUERY HERE>";`.

Comment: I added $sql .= "SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM oc_order_product"; instead of $sql .= " ORDER BY <ADD YOUR SORTING QUERY HERE>";

Comment: And that is wrong, it should be: `$sql .= " ORDER BY SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM oc_order_product";`... Don't You even know the basics of SQL? :-) Notice the `space` and `ORDER BY` at the start. Anyway, the query is wrong, it won't order by anything... Try this one: `$sql .= " ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(product_id) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product GROUP BY product_id)";` but I'm not sure if this is it either...

Answer (score 1):

I've made 2 changes and tested the code to work well:

```
1) remove the (,) in 'bestsellers',
2) updated the sql code to read: 
    $sql .= " ORDER BY (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op where op.product_id=p.product_id GROUP BY p.product_id) ";
```

Here's the code for catalog/model/catalog/product.php:

```
    $sort_data = array(
        'pd.name',
        'p.model',
        'p.quantity',
        'p.price',
        'rating',
        'p.sort_order',
        'p.date_added',
        'bestsellers'
    );  

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
        } else if ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } else if ($data['sort'] == 'bestsellers') { // Sorting as suggested by shadyyx
            $sql .= " ORDER BY (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op where op.product_id=p.product_id GROUP BY p.product_id) ";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";   
    }
```

and the code for catalog\controller\product\product.php:

```
 $data = array(
        'filter_category_id'   => $categories_info['category_id'],
        'sort'                 => 'bestsellers',
        'order'                => 'DESC'
        );
    $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
```

Comment: Your solution also counts products of missing orders, instead try this: " ORDER BY (SELECT sum(quantity) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id and o.order_status_id > '0' GROUP BY p.product_id)"